# Прибавить дни к календарю

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте можно ли как то прибавить к  textView.setText(myDate); 1-5 дней

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private   CalendarView calendarView;
   // Calendar calendar;
   private  Button button;

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                String myDate = "Year: " + year +" - "+  "Month: " +month +" - "+ "Day: " +dayOfMonth;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),myDate,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                textView.setText(myDate);

                }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Переведите в Date добавьте 1 - 5 дней получите что хотите .

Comment: Как это правильно сделать подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
//создаем календарь с вашими данными о годе, месяце и дне
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfMonth);
//доьавляем 5 дней к дате
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 5);
```

Далее можете подставить все что нужно в ваш шаблон:

```
String myDate = "Year: " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) +" - "+  "Month: " +(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + " - "+ "Day: " +calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
```

К месяцу прибавляем 1, потому что отсчет в календаре ведется с 0

Comment: calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfMonth); - это ошибка